# Backtracking in scala parser combinators?

Tags: parsing, scala, option-type, backtracking, combinators

It seems like scala's parser combinators don't backtrack. I have a grammar (see bottom) which can't parse the following "stmt" correctly:

```
copy in to out .
```

That should be easy to parse with backtracking:

```
stmt: (to out(copy in))
```

or am I missing something?

Parser:

```
type ExprP = Parser[Expr]
type ValueP = Parser[ValExpr]
type CallP = Parser[Call]
type ArgsP = Parser[Seq[Expr]]

val ident     = "[a-zA-Z\\+\\-\\*/%><\\\\\\=]+".r
val sqstart   = "\\["                          .r
val sqend     = "\\]"                          .r
val del       = ","                            .r
val end       = "\\."                          .r

def stmt: ExprP      = expr <~ end
def expr: ExprP      = ucall | call | value
def value: ValueP    = ident ^^ {str => IdentExpr(str)}
def call: CallP      = (args ~ ident ~ expr) ^^ {case args ~ method ~ upon => Call(args, method, upon)}
def ucall: CallP     = (ident ~ expr) ^^ {case method ~ upon => Call(Seq(), method, upon)}
def args: ArgsP      = advargs | smplargs
def smplargs: ArgsP  = expr ^^ {e => Seq(e)}
def advargs: ArgsP   = (sqstart ~> repsep(expr, del) <~ sqend) ^^ {seq => seq}
```

Comment: Got it close to working, now I get a stack overflow. Updated parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `PackratParsers` in 2.8.  I think the packrat parser is the only backtracking parser.

Edit: as of mid-year 2015, you should use [fastparse](https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse) instead.  It's not only much faster, but also easier to use (especially when building data structures from parsing).

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix it; I still get SO (from having a left-recursive grammar), and I heard packrat-parsing should be able to fix that. If I make it parse values before calls, then it won't parse (no backtracking?). Maybe I haven't activated packrat parsing, but I made sure to mix in the PackratParsers and return PakratParser from all the functions. Do you know something about PackratParsers?

Comment: Oh, okay, now I found it. To all of you who needs packrat-parsers: Remember to replace "def" with "lazy val", replace "Parser[T]" with "PackratParser[T]" and make the parsers-class/object mix-in from PackratParsers.

Comment: @Anonymous  Please be more clear on your last instruction: "make the parsers-class/object mix-in from PackratParsers". Is that simply "with PackratParsers" for the class?

Comment: @rex fastparse will not handle left-recursion

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is not backtracking.  The standard `|` operator in `scala.util.parsing.combinator` will do backtracking.  Your problem is left-recursion (`expr` → `call` → `args` → `smplargs` → `expr`).  Packrat parsing may indeed help with that.